# SSRS: Logs getting deleted when report is redeployed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Ex: I see that when I deploy a report 'A' on 01/01/2014 and when user hits the reports, I see the logs for that report. After adding some fixes to report 'A ' and then deleting the old version of the report and deploying the new version of the report on the report server with the same report name 'A' on 01/07/2013, I happen to loose all the logs associated with the first version of the report and happen to see only logs from 01/07/2014 for the Version 2 of the report only.

Is there any way I can keep the logs of the report usage of version 1 (that is from 01/01/2014 to 01/07/2014) though I deploy a version 2 with the same name after deleting Version 1 ?

I am getting the SSRS logs from ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have deleted a report and created a new one how can you expect sql server to maintain a chain of two different reports and present you as nothing ever happened to the 1st report :S

Comment: The Version 1 delete is not the real cause for the missing logs, I can say this because after I deleted version 1 and I deployed Version 2 of the report under a different name and saw the logs and I found it still keeps the Version 1 report logs.

Comment: Is deleting a requirement? You can upgrade a report to a new definition without deleting the old version.

Comment: Deleting is not a requirement, in the case of upgrading the new definition solves the issue but I see formatting issues. I am deploying these reports in SharePoint 2013, Browser IE. To avoid the formatting issues I am doing a delete and fresh Upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution logs should remain in dbo.ExecutionLogStorage, *however*, as you deleted the report and then uploaded a truly "new" version of it, the old record in the dbo.Catalog table was deleted, and a new one inserted.  This means the ItemID in the dbo.Catalog table will have changed.  Thus, you can't join on Catalog.ItemID = ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID.

Try looking for records in your dbo.ExecutionLogStorage table that do not have a corresponding record in dbo.Catalog.

Comment: You are right the item ID for the version V1 is getting deleted from Dbo.Catalog then the same ReportID(ItemID) in the ExecutionLogStorage becomes orphan. In order to link the records (Execution Log storage and the deleted record from catlog) I created a delete trigger on Dbo.catlog to get the name and the item id. By this I can have my query to pull the history logs. Thanks everyone.